# KVC compliant setter ?

Tags: objective-c, accessor, key-value-coding

Instead of synthesising my getter/setter I need to define the behaviour of the getter myself.

Doing this, I get a warning telling me I also need to define the setter but I was worried doing this was KVC compliant :

```
- (void) setPath:(NSString *)path {
    _path = path;
}
```

Or do I need to use `setValue:ForKey:` ?

Comment: @Rob, see my answer. If you declare an `@property` using `atomic` (or omit the atomicity specifier, since `atomic` is the default), the compiler will complain if you try to manually implement only one of the accessor methods.

Comment: You've got a good answer, but to clarify: accessors don't need to be KVC-compliant. **Properties** need to be KVC-compliant by having accessors that follow the proper naming conventions. For a property named "path", `-setPath:` is a compliant name. It doesn't matter what that method does, since KVC can't know or care how you implement the property.

Comment: Thanks for completing Andrews answer. I'm quite new at KVO/KVC so everything wasn't completely clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the setter you've posted is KVC/KVO compliant.

That said, why do you have to define both? Is it because the `@property` declaration specifies `atomic`? Assuming that's the case, you should switch to nonatomic. You could make your own accessors atomic, but that's a significant amount of extra work, and unless you have a good, well understood reason for using an `atomic` property, you probably don't need to.

Comment: Well anticipated, I was in fact not defining nonatomic, thanks for the double answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to override just the getter, you still can (and should) <strike>use `@synthesize`</strike> let the compiler auto-sythesize for you. That will synthesize the methods you do not override (in your case, the setter).

Your setter is KVC compliant; it's just unnecessary.

Comment: Perhaps it could be considered good style to use `@synthesize` in this case, but it's not actually necessary. The compiler will still auto-synthesize the setter even if you've manually implemented the getter (and vice versa). It's only if you implement both that auto-synthesis is disabled. In that case, you can use an explicit `@synthesize` to convince the compiler to synthesize an instance variable.

Comment: Sorry; old-time thinking here (from before auto-sythesize). Yes, as Andrew says; there is no reason to use synthesize here directly. You can just let the compiler do it for youj.